# Pegar valor de um campo Span com cURL Parser

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

Estou com uma duvida e um problema. Bom é o seguinte com cURL eu faço o login beleza até até ai tudo bem.. mas preciso pegar algumas informações que estão dentro do html:

```
<span id="Number">12345678993</span>
<span id="holderName">RAFAELA VERCOSA MARIANO</span>
<span id="expirationDate">11/2019</span>
```

A função que estou usando é:

```
function pegar_oneclick(){
   $nome = '';
   $html = str_get_html($this->http_response);
   foreach($html->getElementById('holderName') as $element){
      $text   = $element->plaintext;
      $text   = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), ' ', $text);
      $nome .= str_replace('  ', '', $text);
   }

   return $nome;
}
```

Quero que retorne apenas o *Number: valor*, *holderName: RAFAELA VERCOSA MARIANO* e *expirationDate*, não quero nada pronto apenas uma orientação de como devo fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) ao invés de `getElementById`.

Veja um exemplo usando [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.dom.php):

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');

// Imprimindo os valores
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

// Saída:
// 12345678993
// RAFAELA VERCOSA MARIANO
// 11/2019
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/htXApM)</kbd>

O teu código não funcionava porque através do [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) você procurava somente pela *id* `holderName`. O teu código deveria ficar parecido com isto:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$number = $DOM->getElementById('Number')->nodeValue;
$holdername = $DOM->getElementById('holderName')->nodeValue;
$expirationdate = $DOM->getElementById('expirationDate')->nodeValue;

echo $number. PHP_EOL;         // 12345678993
echo $holdername. PHP_EOL;     // RAFAELA VERCOSA MARIANO
echo $expirationdate. PHP_EOL; // 11/2019
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/CEY8AD)</kbd>

Comment: Boa noite amigo , segui sua orientação e o o mesmo não consegui veja

http://pastebin.com/jn0swJXz

Comment: @Brunohenrique A url têm que ser *https* e não *http*. O código não funciona porque **não há nenhum campo** *Number*, *holderName* ou *expirationDate*. Olhe o código fonte da página e veja!

Comment: Veja aqui , https://privnote.com/n/ohudrgrunbyqeuif/#rrrvsdyaubreyqok