# Pegar valor de <span> site externo

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o conteúdo de um `<span class="exemplo"> "CONTEUDO" </span>` de um site externo. Exemplo: pegar o número de pessoas assistindo uma *streaming* do YouTube.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+dom

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49632/pegar-valor-de-um-campo-span-com-curl-parser/49638#49638